# radio button "Checked" option not working

Tags: php, html

Could you please help me why my checked option in the following code is not working?

```
   <div class="span1">
    <h7>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sex</h7>
    <label class="radio">

    <input id="pccf_sexMF" name="pccf_sexMF" value="M"  type="radio" checked   class="span1" > M
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
    <input id="sexMF" name="pccf_sexMF" value="F"  type="radio"  class="span1"> F
    </label>
   </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: elaborate on "not working"? how is it not working? is it not checked?

Comment: yes it is not checked!

Comment: working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/GPL6d/ you might want to show the rest of any related HTML

Comment: try `checked="checked"`

Comment: already tried this too!

Comment: do you have any javascript running? or other radio buttons checked with the same name? more code please

Comment: No java script!I added the related code here.

Comment: not even checkboxes....sigh

Comment: I'm working on my coleagues' codes; there is no java script and nothing I can think of :( They used bootstrap too!

Comment: Use the Developers tool to make sure you don't have any other element  on top of the radiobuttons. Then use z-index to put the element behind.

Comment: any css? just show us the whole file in jsfiddle.net

Comment: the whole file is too much man!

Comment: @ Hanlet Escaño what is Developers tool? How can I make sure there is no other elements on top of it?

Comment: @ShimaMdz press F12 in Chrome, Firefox or IE to open it. Then you can select/explore the elements. Maybe you can just share a live version with us?

Comment: YEa I tried Fire bug too! and still working on it!

Comment: It was a bug in the code; the ID was the same as another item!Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

It works on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPL6d/)

```
<div class="span1">
    Sex
    <label class="radio">M</label>
    <input id="pccf_sexMF" name="pccf_sexMF" value="M" type="radio" checked="checked" class="span1"/>
    <label class="radio">F</label>
    <input id="sexMF" name="pccf_sexMF" value="F" type="radio" class="span1"/>
</div>
```

- First - no such thing as `h7`
- Only text should be in a label, not the input

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you could have another element with `position:absolute` that will cover your div because its height is bigger than you need it to be. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/8T7Nc/

To avoid this, you can set your div a relative position:

```
<div class="span1" style="position:relative">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/8T7Nc/1/